# What does the 'outermost part' of expression mean in Haskell

Tags: haskell

True beginner here, and I'm reading about the differences between NF and WHNF, and one of the definitions I come across states

> To determine whether an expression is in weak head normal form, we only have to 
>       look at the outermost part of the expression.

I'm not sure what criteria to apply to determine what the 'outermost' part is. For example (from a stack overflow answer by @hammer):

```
'h' : ("e" ++ "llo") -- the outermost part is the data constructor (:)
(1 + 1, 2 + 2)       -- the outermost part is the data constructor (,)
\x -> 2 + 2          -- the outermost part is a lambda abstraction
```

Especially in the first example there, the (:) operator is in the middle of the 'h' and the other expression, so how is it the outermost part?

In general, when looking at an expression, how does one determine what the outermost part is?

Comment: You can desugar `'h' : ("e" ++ "llo")` into `(:) 'h' ((++) "e" "llo")` if that helps, but it isn't about syntactic "outer" its about the data constructor or lambda for the given value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question.  Here, "outermost" (or "topmost") describes the location in reference to a kind of standard, abstract view of the expression that can differ from its actual syntax.  For example, these two expressions:

```
(1, 2)
(,) 1 2
```

have identical meaning in Haskell.  It turns out that in both cases, the constructor `(,)` is the outermost part of the expression, even though the expressions have different syntactic form with the comma appearing in different physical locations in the syntax.

Generally speaking, Haskell's "standard syntax" involves function application of the form:

```
fexpr expr1 .. exprn
```

However, the language also allows other kinds of syntax:

```
1 + 2                -- infix operators
(3, 4)               -- tuples
[5,6,7,8]            -- lists
"abc"                -- strings
```

These alternate syntaxes can be converted to the standard syntax like so:

```
1 + 2   ==>   (+) 1 2
(3, 4)  ==>   (,) 3 4
[5,6,7,8]   ==>  (:) 5 ((:) 6 ((:) 7 ((:) 8 [])))
"abc"   ==>   (:) 'a' ((:) 'b' ((:) 'c' []))
```

Though it's far from obvious, `(+)` is a variable whose value is a function (like `sqrt`); while `(,)` and `(:)` are constructors (just like `True` or `Just`).  Even more confusing and further from obvious, even though `[1,2,3]` is special syntax, the empty list `[]` is a (unary) constructor!  That's why I still used empty lists on the right-hand side in my standard syntax versions.

Anyway, once converted to the standard syntax, an expression will either be a constructor application, like one of these:

```
True               -- a nullary constructor
(,) (1+2) (2+3)    -- constructor expecting two args and fully applied
(:) 5              -- constructor partially applied and expecting one more arg
```

and we say that the "outermost part" of the expression is this constructor application, or it will be an unapplied lambda abstraction:

```
(\x y -> (+) x (length y))
```

and we say that the "outermost part" of the expression is this unapplied lambda abstraction, or it will be something else:

```
w                    -- a variable
(\x -> x) 10         -- an applied lambda abstraction
(f x) y ((*) 2 z)    -- some other function application
(+) 10 (length (1:[]))  -- another function application
```

and we say the "outermost part" of the expression is a variable reference or a function application or whatever.

Anyway, if the outermost part is either a constructor application or an unapplied lambda abstraction, then it's said to be in weak head normal form.  If it's something else, it's not.

So, `Just (5+6)` is in WHNF because the outermost part is the application of the constructor `Just`.  On the other hand, `sqrt (5+6)` is **not** in WHNF because the outermost part is the application of the variable `sqrt`, and a variable isn't a constructor.

Similarly, `5+6` itself is *not* in WHNF because the outermost part is the application of the variable `(+)` to `5` and `6`, while `[5,6]` *is* in WHNF because the outermost part is the application of the (implied) constructor `(:)` to `5` and `[6]`.

Comment: This is such a fantastic explanation. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You have to look at the abstract syntax tree to understand what this means.

```
     :
    / \
  'h'  ++
      /  \
    "e"  "llo"

    (,)
   /  \
  +    +
 / \  / \
1  1  2  2

\x ->
  |
  +
 / \
2   2
```

"Outermost" means the root of the tree.

Comment: This can still be misleading if you consider `undefined ++ "ello"` or `"h" ++ "ello"`.

Comment: What is misleading about those examples?

Comment: WHNF of my examples will be observably different.  If you draw a tree and show `(++)` as the root then the casual reader might think otherwise.  `let !a = undefined ++ "" in 1` vs `let !b = "" ++ "" in 1`.

Comment: I am still not sure where you are coming from. The question is about what "outermost" means in context of determining if a term is in WHNF. If `++` is at the root then it is not in WHNF.